# Vue cli. How to build with the same hash

Tags: docker, vue.js, webpack

i have a problem with hashes in vue cli build.
And now to the details.
I build my app, and in dist folder i see my files with names like 
app.dsadas.js, chunk-1-dsadaas.js etc.. all looks good.
But i build my app in docker images, there may be 2 or more, and i need all this images with the same hashes in filenames, but it is not.
This 'webpack-md5-hash' plugin helped me with this problem, but its very old solution, works with warnings.
Help pls find solution for webpack 4.

This is my vue config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');
const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

const productionGzipExtensions = ['js', 'css'];

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.resolve(__dirname, dir);
}

module.exports = {
  assetsDir: 'static',
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  lintOnSave: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  devServer: {
    overlay: {
      warnings: true,
      errors: true,
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    performance: {
      hints: false,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
      alias: {
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        '@': resolve('src'),
        utils: resolve('src/utils'),
        api: resolve('src/api'),
        defaultStates: resolve('src/store/modules/defaultStates'),
        router: resolve('src/router'),
        store: resolve('src/store'),
        config: resolve('src/config'),
        helpers: resolve('src/store/modules/helpers'),
        constants: resolve('src/constants'),
        mixins: resolve('src/mixins'),
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
      new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
        filename: '[path].gz[query]',
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        test: new RegExp(`\\.(${productionGzipExtensions.join('|')})$`),
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: The best approach would be disabling hash for the assets only